# How do I convert a list in a Pandas DF into a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame.  One of the columns contains a list.  I want that column to be a single string.

For example my list `['one','two','three']` should simply be `'one, two, three'`

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(df['col'].astype(str)))
```

gives me `['one, two, three],['four','five','six']`  where the second list is from the next row. Needless to say with millions of rows this concatenation across rows is not only incorrect, it kills my memory.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should certainly not convert to string before you transform the list. Try:

```
df['col'].apply(', '.join)
```

Also note that `apply` applies the function to the elements of the series, so using `df['col']` in the lambda function is probably not what you want.

---

Or, there is a native [`.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) method, but it is (surprisingly) a bit slower than `apply`.

Comment: what if items of the list are `int` types

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti this should work: `df['col'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)))`

Comment: what about if there is some nan data.  `df2['well_array2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x if pd.isnull(all(x))==False)) ` did not work. I am getting error float' object is not iterable

Comment: neither this is working, getting the same error. `df2['well_array2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x if type(x) == type([])))`

Comment: @IanS the entire x is nan, there is no list at this row in well_array2 column. Thanks in advance. I do not want to filter out nan values!

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti this should work: `df['new_col'] = df['col'].dropna().apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)))`

Comment: This filters out null values, but reassigns them when you create the new column (because pandas does index-based assignment, missing values are assigned nan).

Comment: I'm not a Pandas expert, but it seems like the reason to prefer `.str.join()` is that it accounts for NaN and other objects automatically. For example use `pd.Series([np.nan, ['one', 'two', 'three']])` and compare the two methods.

Answer (score 13):

When you cast `col` to `str` with `astype`, you get a string representation of a python list, brackets and all. You do not need to do that, just `apply` `join` directly:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
    })

# Out[8]: 
#            A
# 0  [a, b, c]
# 1  [A, B, C]

df['Joined'] = df.A.apply(', '.join)

#            A   Joined
# 0  [a, b, c]  a, b, c
# 1  [A, B, C]  A, B, C
```

Comment: When I tried this, it performed it at the letter level rather than the word.

Comment: And you don't have this issue with a lambda function?

Comment: That means that your column is a string rather than a list. You can convert it back using `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Although in this case, it would be faster to just do `df['col'].str.replace('[\[,\]]', '')`

Answer (score 9):

You could convert your list to str with `astype(str)` and then remove `'`, `[`, `]` characters. Using @Yakim example:

```
In [114]: df
Out[114]:
           A
0  [a, b, c]
1  [A, B, C]

In [115]: df.A.astype(str).str.replace('\[|\]|\'', '')
Out[115]:
0    a, b, c
1    A, B, C
Name: A, dtype: object
```

**Timing**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]})
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)


In [2]: timeit df['A'].apply(', '.join)
292 µs ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [3]: timeit df['A'].str.join(', ')
368 µs ± 24.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: timeit df['A'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
505 µs ± 5.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [5]: timeit df['A'].str.replace('\[|\]|\'', '')
2.43 ms ± 62.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. However, I timed your method, and it is slower than `apply` by a factor of 5.

Comment: @IanS how did you time it? I thought vectorized string operations as shown in this answer would be much faster than     apply

Comment: @Shoof I used the `%timeit` magic in IPython. I checked again and I find 3 times as slow on a column with 100 rows. Two possible explanations: 1) Regex replace operations, even vectorized, can be quite slow. 2) Apply is smart, e.g. if you apply a standard function such as `sum` it will be quite fast. I assume something similar may be going on with `join`.

Comment: @Shoof @IanS I edited answer to add timings. And add new method with `str.join` which is on 2nd place after `.apply(', '.join)`

Comment: @IanS thanks a lot for the timed results! That's indeed a bit surprising as some books suggested otherwise. Great to see the comparisons!

Comment: It's interesting that `str.join` is slower (but then, only by a bit). Note that operations on objects cannot really be vectorized since an `object` column is just a column of pointers (here, to lists).

Answer (score 2):

Pandas offers a method for this, [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html).

Comment: `Series.str.join(', ')` works well for me. As stated by the documentation, "The lists containing object(s) of types other than str will produce a NaN." For my use case, this was preferable to an error, which is what I got when using `Series.apply(', '.join)`.