# Convert Pandas column with list to string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert pandas dataframe column which has `list for each row` to `string in each row` but somehow it not converting.
Here is what I have tried from [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306988/column-of-lists-convert-list-to-string-as-a-new-column).

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient = 'index') # save the given data below in dict variable to run this line
```

first approach:

```
data['tags'] = data['Tags'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, x)))
```

second approach:

```
data['tags']=[''.join(map(str,item)) for item in data['Tags']]
```

but both of these gives me same list of strings in `tags` column. As shown below,

```
0    ['python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm']
1                         ['converters', 'dxf', 'dwg']
2                           ['python', 'regex', 'nlp']
3          ['sql', 'join', 'dynamic', 'logic', 'case']
4                   ['r-markdown', 'hugo', 'blogdown']
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

**and I want in this form**

```
0    'python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm'
1                         'converters', 'dxf', 'dwg'
2                           'python', 'regex', 'nlp'
3          'sql', 'join', 'dynamic', 'logic', 'case'
4                   'r-markdown', 'hugo', 'blogdown'
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

Here is the data (first 5 rows) using data.head(5).to_dict(orient = 'index')

```
{'Tags': {0: "['python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm']",
  1: "['converters', 'dxf', 'dwg']",
  2: "['python', 'regex', 'nlp']",
  3: "['sql', 'join', 'dynamic', 'logic', 'case']",
  4: "['r-markdown', 'hugo', 'blogdown']"},
 'cleaned_text': {0: 'matter pip version instal specific python version read round still stuck upgrade python 3 7 x python 3 8 1 windows 10 go cmd prompt check pip instal module',
  1: 'convert dwg dxf node php jave etc convert dwg file dxf node js python java already try ogr2ogr success thank advance',
  2: 'match text base string list extract subsection python try generate structure earning call text look like following sample operator lady gentleman thank stand welcome xyz fourth quarter',
  3: 'sql dynamically join table various column first time posting use case want join sale datum master agreement table determine applicable fee transactional level hard part agreement',
  4: 'ok update hugo run 2 year old version hugo academic theme blogdown late version hugo ubuntu 19 10 repos 0 58 new version 0 65 download hugo website'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my issue seems like `'['a','b','d']'` which doesn't appear in dataframe but thanks to @Quang Hoang, he pointed out in my output data which i gave in question. It can also be solved with `ast.literal_eval()`

```
import ast
data['tags'] = [ast.literal_eval(item) for item in data['Tags']]
```

Output:

```
0    'python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm'
1                         'converters', 'dxf', 'dwg'
2                           'python', 'regex', 'nlp'
3          'sql', 'join', 'dynamic', 'logic', 'case'
4                   'r-markdown', 'hugo', 'blogdown'
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

Here, `literal_eval()` evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. To know more about it and when and how to use refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) question

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is:

```py
data['tags'] = data['Tags'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

Example

```py
ser = pd.Series([['python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm'],
                 ['converters', 'dxf', 'dwg'],
                 ['python', 'regex', 'nlp'],
                 ['sql', 'join', 'dynamic', 'logic', 'case'],
                 ['r-markdown', 'hugo', 'blogdown']])

ser.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

will produce

```
0    python windows pip pygame pycharm
1                   converters dxf dwg
2                     python regex nlp
3          sql join dynamic logic case
4             r-markdown hugo blogdown
dtype: object
```

---

If you want it **exactly** like you show then you can do the following

```py
ser.apply(lambda x: "'" + "', '".join(x) + "'")
```

which will produce

```
0    'python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm'
1                         'converters', 'dxf', 'dwg'
2                           'python', 'regex', 'nlp'
3          'sql', 'join', 'dynamic', 'logic', 'case'
4                   'r-markdown', 'hugo', 'blogdown'
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
data['Tags'] = data['Tags'].str[1:-1]
```

Output `data['Tags']`

```
0    'python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm'
1                         'converters', 'dxf', 'dwg'
2                           'python', 'regex', 'nlp'
3          'sql', 'join', 'dynamic', 'logic', 'case'
4                   'r-markdown', 'hugo', 'blogdown'
Name: Tags, dtype: object
```

Comment: it gives like this... 0    [ ' p y t h o n ' ,   ' w i n d o w s ' ,   ' p i p ' ,   ' p y g a m e ' ,   ' p y c h a r m ' ]
1                                              [ ' c o n v e r t e r s ' ,   ' d x f ' ,   ' d w g ' ]
2                                                  [ ' p y t h o n ' ,   ' r e g e x ' ,   ' n l p ' ]
3                [ ' s q l ' ,   ' j o i n ' ,   ' d y n a m i c ' ,   ' l o g i c ' ,   ' c a s e ' ]
4                                  [ ' r - m a r k d o w n ' ,   ' h u g o ' ,   ' b l o g d o w n ' ]
Name: tags, dtype: object

Comment: Looks likes the thing is not list, but list-like string. Try `data['Tags'].str[1:-1]`.

Comment: It gives this...and this is surprising to me. 0    'python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm'
1                         'converters', 'dxf', 'dwg'
2                           'python', 'regex', 'nlp'
3          'sql', 'join', 'dynamic', 'logic', 'case'
4                   'r-markdown', 'hugo', 'blogdown'
Name: Tags, dtype: object

Comment: Can you pls tell what is going on?

Comment: As shown in your dict data: `"['python', 'windows', 'pip', 'pygame', 'pycharm']"` is a string, not a list. What I did was just stripping the first and last characters, which are the square brackets.

Comment: How does `str[1:-1]` convert list into string? and moreover, when i tired `str[:-1]` it returns same list of string.

Comment: It doesn't. The point is that your data **is not list**, it is string that looks like a list when printed out.

Comment: sorry but i still didn't get `str[1:-1]` part here? can you explain this what it is doing?