# Combine rows in pandas df as per given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas df as shown

```
 Name     Subject   Score
 Rakesh   Math      65
 Mukesh   Science   76
 Bhavesh  French    87
 Rakesh   Science   88
 Rakesh   Hindi     76
 Sanjay   English   66
 Mukesh   English   98
 Mukesh   Marathi   77
```

I have to make another df including students who took two or more subjects and total their scores in each subjects.

Hence the resultant df will be as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas, there is a method `explode` that will take a column that contains lists and break them apart. We can do a sort of opposite of that by making list of your Subjects column. I pulled the idea here from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235312/how-to-implodereverse-of-pandas-explode-based-on-a-column).

```py
In [1]: df =  df.groupby('Name').agg({'Subject': lambda x: x.tolist(), 'Score':'sum'})

In [2]: df

Out[2]:
                             Subject  Score
Name
Bhavesh                     [French]     87
Mukesh   [Science, English, Marathi]    251
Rakesh        [Math, Science, Hindi]    229
Sanjay                     [English]     66
```

We can then filter on the `Subject` column for any row where the list has more than one item. This method I lifted from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340341/how-to-determine-the-length-of-lists-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column).

```py
In [3]: df[df['Subject'].str.len() > 1]
Out[3]:
                            Subject  Score
Name
Mukesh  [Science, English, Marathi]    251
Rakesh       [Math, Science, Hindi]    229
```

If you want the `Subject` column to be a string instead of a list, you can utulize this [third other-answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023810/convert-pandas-column-with-list-to-string).

```py
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
```

Comment: Note that in the first line it could be simply `.agg({'Subject': list, ...`

Comment: likewise the last line can also simply be `.apply(", ".join)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby`, `filter` and `agg` we can do it in one line:

```
(df.groupby('Name')
   .filter(lambda g:len(g)>1)
   .groupby('Name')
   .agg({'Subject': ', '.join, 'Score':'sum'})
)
```

output

```
        Subject                     Score
Name        
Mukesh  Science, English, Marathi   251
Rakesh  Math, Science, Hindi        229
```