# Unwanted String remove from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I greatly appreciate your effort in trying to work out the formula to delete bracket and apostrophe    but so far it hasn't quite worked.

```
Data
['IMI', ‘50’]

Out put Should be like this
IMI,50
```

I used this method but not working

```
dataFrame['group_code'] = dataFrame['groups'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([s[1:-1] for s in x]))
```

Comment: Does the column contain a string or a list? If it's a string, you're just removing the first and last chracters, then putting `,` between all the other characters, which isn't what you want. If it's a list, you shouldn't slice it, just use `','.join(s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column contains strings, you should use `.str.replace()` to remove the characters you don't want:

```
dataframe['groups'].str.replace(r"[\[\]']", "", regex=True)
```

If the column contains lists, don't slice it, since the brackets aren't list elements.

```
dataframe['groups'].apply(lambda l: ','.join(l))
```

See [Pandas Column join list values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66001096/pandas-column-join-list-values)