# How to Group by from the list of data in the column and do the operation

Tags: pandas

Below is df, I need to analyze the data.

```
   gender   dob          list
0   M   01/01/87    [['Office/Work'],['31-35'], ['Salaried']]
1   M   01/01/94    [[Movies,Restaurants'],['21-25'], ['Salaried']]
2   M   01/01/95    [['College/Park'],['21-25'],['Student']] 
3   F   01/01/97    [['College'], ['21-25'], ['Student']]
```

Expected Out
1. I need to analyse how many salaried are there in the dataset

df['salaried']

`Total = 2,
Male = 2,
Female = 0`

2. How many student are there in the list
   df['students']

`Total = 2,
Male = 1,
Female = 1`

3. How many are going to Movies
   df['Movies']

`Total = 1,
Male = 1, 
Female=0`

4. Group by different age group
   df['age_group']

   `Age_Group Total Male Female
   ['21-25']  3  2 1
   ['31-35']  1  1 0`
5. What is the percentage of Male to Female

`round(len(df.loc[df['gender'] == 'M']) / (len(df.loc[df['gender'] == 'M']) + len(df.loc[df['gender'] == 'F'])),2)*100`

Comment: Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity, its actually a problem. I have done with very long solution which is not that up to mark. Got stuck so put a question. You can take up the issue

Comment: how do you want your final df to look like. i know you have posted the expected results, but if you can post the dataframe expected, that'd help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use `explode` to split column's lists of element into rows.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'gender':['M','M','M','F'],'B':[[['Office/Work'],['31-35'], ['Salaried']],[['Movies,Restaurants'],['21-25'], ['Salaried']],[[
'College/Park'],['21-25'],['Student']],[['College'], ['21-25'], ['Student']]]})
```

**df:**

```
  gender                                            B
0      M         [[Office/Work], [31-35], [Salaried]]
1      M  [[Movies,Restaurants], [21-25], [Salaried]]
2      M         [[College/Park], [21-25], [Student]]
3      F              [[College], [21-25], [Student]]
```

---

```
x=df.explode('B')
```

---

**x:**

```
  gender                     B
0      M         [Office/Work]
0      M               [31-35]
0      M            [Salaried]
1      M  [Movies,Restaurants]
1      M               [21-25]
1      M            [Salaried]
2      M        [College/Park]
2      M               [21-25]
2      M             [Student]
3      F             [College]
3      F               [21-25]
3      F             [Student]
```

---

```
x['B']=x.B.astype(str) 
final_df=x.groupby(['B','gender']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

---

**final_df:**

```
gender                  F  M
B                           
['21-25']               1  2
['31-35']               0  1
['College']             1  0
['College/Park']        0  1
['Movies,Restaurants']  0  1
['Office/Work']         0  1
['Salaried']            0  2
['Student']             1  1
```

You can compute total using F, M columns.

Comment: `df_final_resp.assign(final_resp=df_final_resp.final_resp.str.split('],').replace('[','')).explode('final_resp').head()` your code didn't work for me, I have done above one, can you tell me what could be the reason

Comment: You can use `df['col'].apply(', '.join)` in place of `df_final_resp.final_resp.str.split('],').replace('[',''))`  source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347725/converting-a-panda-df-list-into-a-string/37347837

Comment: The reason it's not working because you are making your list as a string. explode works for list. So you should first explode as I did. If you don't want bracket do this : `x['B'] =x['B'].apply(''.join)`

Comment: Just replace `x['B']=x.B.astype(str)` with  `x['B'] =x['B'].apply(''.join)` and you are ready to go.