# Concatenate a column of lists within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas and one of my columns is a set of lists; however, some of the lists in the column have more elements than others:

```
df['Name'].head()
```

Output:

```
0 ['Andrew', '24']
1 ['James']
2 ['Billy', '19', 'M']
3 ['Grace', '42']
4 ['Amy']
```

Is it possible for me to concatenate each element in each list together, while still maintaining my df?

Desired output:

```
0 'Andrew24'
1 'James'
2 'Billy19M'
3 'Grace42'
4 'Amy'
```

I tried many different things; the closest I got was using the snip below but this concatenated all of the lists together in each record:

```
def concatenate_list_data(list):
    result= ''
    for element in list:
       result += str(element)
    return result
df['Name'] = concatenate_list_data(df['Name'])`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column of lists, convert list to string as a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306988/column-of-lists-convert-list-to-string-as-a-new-column)

Comment: There’s also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347725/converting-a-panda-df-list-into-a-string/37347837

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Name'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x)
```

Output:

```
0    Andrew24
1       James
2    Billy19M
3     Grace42
4         Amy
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Or just `df['Name'].agg(''.join)`

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why use this over the functionality provided directly by Pandas...?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas offers a method for this, [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html): `df['Name'].str.join('')`.

Comment: I couldn't get that to change anything

Comment: @AndrewVitek That’s really bizarre, what output did you get? Did you try printing the result, before assigning it back to the DataFrame?

Comment: You might want to redefine the column as `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.join('')` I'm not sure the function has `inplace=True` as default behavior

Comment: @CeliusStingher Oh of course, what I shared wouldn’t change the DataFrame alone, it’s just a Series method.